# Compare text corpora

Tags: machine-learning, topic-models

I have am currently performing speech recognition experiments on 2 different corpora. I have the ground truth human-labelled texts for both corpora. I am performing different experiments that lead to different recognition performance on both corpora. Specifically, some changes bring improvements to one corpus while decreasing the quality in the second corpus and vice-versa.

I would like to identify key differences between the text ground truths I possess. My current idea is to use topic modelling, for example, LDA to look at differences in topics. Another approach could be to look at word frequencies. However, the frequencies of common and rare words seem to be the same in both cases.

Any recommendation as to how I could identify the differences in the corpora that might lead to such variations?

Answer (score 0):

LDA and frequent words are good ideas. Some additional ideas:

- Have you looked at the data? Before doing any unsupervised learning method such as LDA or descriptive stats, just look at the samples. For instance, these 2 methods do not give you any insights about anything pertaining to word order or sentence length. Maybe in one corpus the sentences are longer?
- Looking at the text is looking at the outputs, but maybe the inputs explain the difference in performance you get. For instance, maybe one of the corpora has noisier inputs? Or the set of speaker is more diverse? Again, look at the data before everything, then try to quantify with methods such as frequency analysis if you suspect anything.